# Encode base64 in Python and decode in C#

Tags: c#, python

I'm trying to base64 encode a string in python and then decode in C#,
and as far as I can see right now, the problem is that base64.b64encoding from python is encoding in ASCII. And when i use Convert.FromBase64String it uses unicode..

Python :

```
msg = cipher.encrypt("hello")
msgb64 = base64.b64encode(msg)
```

> Encoded message: 
>   b'UORSfV0=', cipher text before encoding: b'P\xe4R}]'

C# :

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("UORSfV0=");
string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

> To show the output in string show this before aes decryption : "PäR}]"

From this step the error starts, because its not the cipher text

Any suggestions for a solution to this?

Comment: `UORSfV0 =` is not the same as `UORSfV0=`, there's an extra space in the c# code

Comment: ASCII is the 7-bit character set of characters between 0 and 127. The string you posted contains *escape sequences* outside that range. You should specify the *correct* codepage while decoding the buffer

Comment: In any case .NET uses Unicode, not ASCII. SO runs on .NET so you can post the *actual* string in the question, not the escaped form, eg `PäR}]`. Use UTF8 in Python as well, to avoid having to guess the correct codepage

Comment: Ehmmm, why are you converting the buffer to a *string* at all? AES works on buffers, not strings. Did you encounter *another* problem and assumed that somehow Base64 didn't work?

Comment: And anyway, there's nothing wrong with .NET or Base64. If you use the *wrong* codepage you get the *wrong* data. Python does *NOT* use ASCII and the evidence is your very own code and question. `\xe4` is outside the ASCII range

Comment: You mentioned in the comments that you want to send that string to a web service. You already have a string you can use, the base64 string. Web services allow byte arrays through the `base64binary` type. Web service proxies in .NET do this automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AES deals with byte buffers, not strings. There's no reason to convert the buffer to a string before decrypting. Besides, that string is way too short for AES. How the *byte buffer* looks using various codepages has nothing to do with whether the *byte values* are correct.

I suspect there's a problem with the decryption code which wasn't posted. The OP attempted to convert the buffer to a string in order to compare the values. Base64 isn't broken though. There's no reason to look for bugs that weren't noticed by any .NET developer for over 15 years.

Without the code that attempts to decrypt the `bytes` buffer it's impossible to say what's wrong. That string looks way too short for AES though.

The rest is only meant to explain where `?` came from and why.

**Original Answer**

There are multiple problems with this code. The Base64 string you used on the C# side has an extra space.

Even after that's fixed, the codepage is definitely wrong. [Encoding.ASCII](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii(v=vs.100).aspx) is the 7-bit character set while the Python string contains `\xe4`, ie `ä`. This is neither an ASCII nor a UTF8 string. The character is definitely outside the valid range. You need to *know* the correct codepage to use to decode it.

Without knowing the actual codepage one can only guess.  One codepage that can decode this character is 1253, ie Latin1. If you use :

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("UORSfV0=");
string s = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(bytes);
```

You'll get back `PäR}]`

If you used 1253 though you'd get `PδR}]`. 1251 would return `PдR}]`. Which one did you intent to use?

The only thing you can be certain about is that some codepages will fail and return `?`, or the well defined Unicode Replacement Character `�`

To avoid conversion errors you should use UTF8 on Python and C#. C# and Windows in general uses Unicode (UTF16 specifically), which is why I could post those characters in the answer. No special encoding was involved. Most file-related classes use UTF8 by default and return Unicode strings.

Comment: But this is not string in any encoding. This is result of encryption (`cipher.encrypt`), so it's arbitrary byte array.

Comment: @Evk I dealt only with the encoding issue because we have no idea what `encrypt` does. The OP encoded it using `base64.b64encode(msg)` and said its value *before* encoding was `P\xe4R}]`. That's not ASCII. That's guaranteed to mangle the data. I don't know what `cipher.encrypt` is supposed to do but the result is definitely too short for AES

Comment: Well that string is what OP sees when he prints result of encrypt in python console. So it's not a meaningful string in any encoding, it is byte array which python prints to console like this.

Comment: @Evk using ASCII resulted in *lost* data, ie the `?` character. If you mean the OP shouldn't have tried to decode the buffer, yes. He probably got another error (that's way too short for AES) and thought the buffer didn't contain the correct data. Instead of comparing byte values, he converted it to text using the wrong codepage

Comment: Yes, OP should not convert that byte array (converted from base64 string) to string, because it's not a string. And major part of your answer suggests to do something with encodings and codepages, says " use UTF8 on Python" - all that is irrelevant, result of `encrypt` on python side is NOT a string. And by the way, `Convert.FromBase64String("UORSfV0=")` and `Convert.FromBase64String("UORSfV0 =")` produces exactly the same byte array.

Comment: @Evk I'm done trying to triple guess. The OP asked about Base64 and encodings. You made a double guess that this is irrelevant, and I agree. To understand we need another guess and that's enough. I'm certain the string is truncated.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have to convert result to string, because I need to send it to a web service. I cannot send byte array to the web service:/

Comment: @KunoHeltborg you can. It will be encoded and sent as base64 in fact - XSD has a `base64binary` type for this. In any case, you *already* have a Base64 string, why are you decoding it and trying to convert it to a *different* string?

Comment: @KunoHeltborg It looks like you have a problem you haven't explained yet and assumed it had something to do with Base64. Unless you ask about your *real* problem, you won't get a good answer. You are forcing people to guess what you want

Answer (score 0):

Try `Default` Encoding

> `byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("UORSfV0 =");`
>   `string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);`

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("UORSfV0 =");
string s = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: `Default` is *your machine's* encoding. It doesn't mean that's the codepage used by the machine that generated the data. If the machines have different encodings you'll end up with mangled data, only you won't be able to detect it

Answer (score 0):

I had some time to develop this Solution for Python3.7, considering as example:

```
'''        Argument =   [110, 13, 46, 136, 95, 66, 92, 132, 109, 217, 58, 112, 43, 8, 145, 
                         42, 233, 98, 40, 139, 165, 228, 52, 9, 89, 175, 146, 103, 227, 238, 233, 190, 
                         78, 175, 242, 224, 202, 138, 248, 103, 114, 98, 199, 252, 80, 86, 61, 174]
            return =    'bg0uiF9CXIRt2TpwKwiRKuliKIul5DQJWa+SZ+Pu6b5Or/Lgyor4Z3Jix/xQVj2u' 
'''
```

Like this:

```
import base64
import numpy as np


# Do the same as Convert.FromBase64String() from C#
def ConvertFromBase64String(encrypted):
    return np.frombuffer(base64.b64decode(encrypted.encode()), np.uint8)

# Do the oposite of Convert.FromBase64String() from C#
def ConvertToBase64String(encrypted):
    return (base64.b64encode(textoUnicodeToUtf8Literal(("".join([chr(item) for item in np.array(encrypted, dtype=np.uint8)]))).encode('ISO-8859-1'))).decode()



def textoUnicodeToUtf8Literal(encodando):
    return encodando.replace("\xc2\x80", r'\x80').replace("\xc2\x81", r'\x81').replace("\xc2\x82", r'\x82')\
        .replace("\xc2\x83", r'\x83').replace("\xc2\x84", r'\x84').replace("\xc2\x85", r'\x85')\
        .replace("\xc2\x86", r'\x86').replace("\xc2\x87", r'\x87').replace("\xc2\x88", r'\x88')\
        .replace("\xc2\x89", r'\x89').replace("\xc2\x8a", r'\x8A').replace("\xc2\x8b", r'\x8B')\
        .replace("\xc2\x8c", r'\x8C').replace("\xc2\x8d", r'\x8D').replace("\xc2\x8e", r'\x8E')\
        .replace("\xc2\x8f", r'\x8F').replace("\xc2\x90", r'\x90').replace("\xc2\x91", r'\x91')\
        .replace("\xc2\x92", r'\x92').replace("\xc2\x93", r'\x93').replace("\xc2\x94", r'\x94')\
        .replace("\xc2\x95", r'\x95').replace("\xc2\x96", r'\x96').replace("\xc2\x97", r'\x97')\
        .replace("\xc2\x98", r'\x98').replace("\xc2\x99", r'\x99').replace("\xc2\x9a", r'\x9A')\
        .replace("\xc2\x9b", r'\x9B').replace("\xc2\x9c", r'\x9C').replace("\xc2\x9d", r'\x9D')\
        .replace("\xc2\x9e", r'\x9E').replace("\xc2\x9f", r'\x9F').replace("\xc2\xa0", r'\xA0')\
        .replace("\xc2\xa1", r'\xA1').replace("\xc2\xa2", r'\xA2').replace("\xc2\xa3", r'\xA3')\
        .replace("\xc2\xa4", r'\xA4').replace("\xc2\xa5", r'\xA5').replace("\xc2\xa6", r'\xA6')\
        .replace("\xc2\xa7", r'\xA7').replace("\xc2\xa8", r'\xA8').replace("\xc2\xa9", r'\xA9')\
        .replace("\xc2\xaa", r'\xAA').replace("\xc2\xab", r'\xAB').replace("\xc2\xac", r'\xAC')\
        .replace("\xc2\xad", r'\xAD').replace("\xc2\xae", r'\xAE').replace("\xc2\xaf", r'\xAF')\
        .replace("\xc2\xb0", r'\xB0').replace("\xc2\xb1", r'\xB1').replace("\xc2\xb2", r'\xB2')\
        .replace("\xc2\xb3", r'\xB3').replace("\xc2\xb4", r'\xB4').replace("\xc2\xb5", r'\xB5')\
        .replace("\xc2\xb6", r'\xB6').replace("\xc2\xb7", r'\xB7').replace("\xc2\xb8", r'\xB8')\
        .replace("\xc2\xb9", r'\xB9').replace("\xc2\xba", r'\xBA').replace("\xc2\xbb", r'\xBB')\
        .replace("\xc2\xbc", r'\xBC').replace("\xc2\xbd", r'\xBD').replace("\xc2\xbe", r'\xBE')\
        .replace("\xc2\xbf", r'\xBF').replace("\xc3\x80", r'\xC0').replace("\xc3\x81", r'\xC1')\
        .replace("\xc3\x82", r'\xC2').replace("\xc3\x83", r'\xC3').replace("\xc3\x84", r'\xC4')\
        .replace("\xc3\x85", r'\xC5').replace("\xc3\x86", r'\xC6').replace("\xc3\x87", r'\xC7')\
        .replace("\xc3\x88", r'\xC8').replace("\xc3\x89", r'\xC9').replace("\xc3\x8a", r'\xCA')\
        .replace("\xc3\x8b", r'\xCB').replace("\xc3\x8c", r'\xCC').replace("\xc3\x8d", r'\xCD')\
        .replace("\xc3\x8e", r'\xCE').replace("\xc3\x8f", r'\xCF').replace("\xc3\x90", r'\xD0')\
        .replace("\xc3\x91", r'\xD1').replace("\xc3\x92", r'\xD2').replace("\xc3\x93", r'\xD3')\
        .replace("\xc3\x94", r'\xD4').replace("\xc3\x95", r'\xD5').replace("\xc3\x96", r'\xD6')\
        .replace("\xc3\x97", r'\xD7').replace("\xc3\x98", r'\xD8').replace("\xc3\x99", r'\xD9')\
        .replace("\xc3\x9a", r'\xDA').replace("\xc3\x9b", r'\xDB').replace("\xc3\x9c", r'\xDC')\
        .replace("\xc3\x9d", r'\xDD').replace("\xc3\x9e", r'\xDE').replace("\xc3\x9f", r'\xDF')\
        .replace("\xc3\xa0", r'\xE0').replace("\xc3\xa1", r'\xE1').replace("\xc3\xa2", r'\xE2')\
        .replace("\xc3\xa3", r'\xE3').replace("\xc3\xa4", r'\xE4').replace("\xc3\xa5", r'\xE5')\
        .replace("\xc3\xa6", r'\xE6').replace("\xc3\xa7", r'\xE7').replace("\xc3\xa8", r'\xE8')\
        .replace("\xc3\xa9", r'\xE9').replace("\xc3\xaa", r'\xEA').replace("\xc3\xab", r'\xEB')\
        .replace("\xc3\xac", r'\xEC').replace("\xc3\xad", r'\xED').replace("\xc3\xae", r'\xEE')\
        .replace("\xc3\xaf", r'\xEF').replace("\xc3\xb0", r'\xF0').replace("\xc3\xb1", r'\xF1')\
        .replace("\xc3\xb2", r'\xF2').replace("\xc3\xb3", r'\xF3').replace("\xc3\xb4", r'\xF4')\
        .replace("\xc3\xb5", r'\xF5').replace("\xc3\xb6", r'\xF6').replace("\xc3\xb7", r'\xF7')\
        .replace("\xc3\xb8", r'\xF8').replace("\xc3\xb9", r'\xF9').replace("\xc3\xba", r'\xFA')\
        .replace("\xc3\xbb", r'\xFB').replace("\xc3\xbc", r'\xFC').replace("\xc3\xbd", r'\xFD')\
        .replace("\xc3\xbe", r'\xFE').replace("\xc3\xbf", r'\xFF')
```